# How to configure cache directory in Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, caching, parameters, configuration, containers

With Symfony 3, the AppKernel allows us to define the cache directory with AppKernel::getCacheDir() method.
I would like to configure the cache directory from a parameter :

```
#app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    cache_dir: /var/cache/symfony/
```

And implement the AppKernel::getCacheDir() method :

```
#app/AppKernel.php
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return $this->getContainer()->getParameter('cache_dir');
    }
```

The problem is that the Kernel is not booted when the getCacheDir() method is called the first time.

[image: Call to a member function getParameter() on null]

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

The Container can't be initialized before the Kernel was booted. 
The `getCacheDir` is called while booting the Kernel.

You can't access the container at that time.

You have at least 2 options:

1. Hardcode the path into the function without using parameters.
2. Manually parse the contents of `parameters.yml` without using services from the container (through fgetcontents and a manually instantiated YamlParser for example).

Answer (score 0):

That's because container also needs to be cached when it's being created.
You have sort of invalid dependence cycle here. To create the container, you need a value that you want to get from this container.

If container is already generated cached previously, you want to know where to look for it, but to do that you're trying to access this container.

That's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your method and parse the file directly with Yaml::parse() :

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    $value = \Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse(file_get_contents(dirname(__DIR__).'/app/config/parameters.yml'));
    return $value['parameters']['cache_dir'];
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but the parameters like "'%kernel.project_dir%" are not replaced